# RegEx: Defining some exceptions for replacement

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to convert the beginning of each sentence into upercase character. That is working so far.
But I also need to define some exception (abbrevations). After those abbrevations, the next word should not be converted to upper case.

This is what I have tried, but it doesn't work:

```
const abbrevs = ['ign.'];
var regex = new RegExp('(?!' + abbrevs.join('|') + ').+?(?:[.?!]\s|$)', 'g');
string.replace(regex, function(s) { return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1); })
```

*Example*

```
this ign. is an example. this should get capitalized
```

should get:

```
This ign. is an example. This should get capitalized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could :

- replace `'ign.'` and every other abbreviation by `'abbreviation<ign>'` or `'some_keyword_probably_not_found_in_strings<ign>'`
- apply uppercase to the beginnig of each sentence
- convert every `abbreviation<ign>` back to `ign.`.

Here's an example :

```js
const abbrevs = ['ign', 'abc'];
var string = "this ign. is an example. this abc. is another example. this should get capitalized.";

console.log(string);

abbrevs.forEach(function(abbrev) {
  string = string.replace(new RegExp(abbrev+'\.', 'g'), 'abbreviation<'+abbrev+'>');
});

console.log(string);

function applySentenceCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/.+?[\.\?\!](\s|$)/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}
string = applySentenceCase(string);

console.log(string);

string = string.replace(new RegExp('abbreviation<(.*?)>', 'g'), "$1.");

console.log(string);
```

Comment: Is it possible to ignore all abbrevations, which have the format `singleCharacter dot singleCharacter dot`? It would it make easier, because the abbrevs-list would be smaller.